# Python import file in another file path ERROR 'Nomudulenamed'

Tags: python, import, module

I have python files that are saved in A folder, B folder and C folder with three functions.

A, B and C folders are in 'Project' folder on the desktop(Desktop/Project/A)

In A folder, I have two python files 'a' and 'b',

Now, In file 'b' and I want to import 'a' module in the same path in Desktop/Project/A

I simply used:

```
import A.a as a
```

But got the error:

```
No module named 'A'
```

Could you please help with that? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you add `__init__.py` to folder A? If not, you should add one

In `__init__.py` in folder A

```py
import a
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, do I just need import a in '_init_'file, but after that, still no module named error

Comment: I read your question again carefully. In file `b.py` you should add folder A to system path

In `b.py` 
```python
import sys
sys.path.append('../A')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I am trying the code now

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use

```
import A.a
```

If it's in the same directory then just call

```
import a
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But if I want some py file in Folder B, should I use init arg?